# SQLite forces x86 on Windows Phone, but can't run x86 on WP Devices?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

So I'm trying to add SQLite to my Windows Phone app, and the tutorial I followed had me add the Extensions to Visual Studio 2013, then add the Nuget Packages. These caused errors, which the tutorial predicted and told me the solution was to change my packages to x86 in the Configuration Manager. I did this and the errors went away as planned. However, you can't deploy x86 apps to a Windows Phone, so... how do you use SQLite for Windows Phone apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you link the tutorials you used?

As for the platform problems set it to ARM

Clean -> Rebuild -> Deploy

Screenshot for clarity.

[image]

Comment: Changing it to ARM worked! Thanks!

Here's the Tutorial I followed: http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/04/universal-app-with-sqlite-part-1/

Comment: @neochronomo I have no idea how he got those settings to actually work.  It would probably compile but I doubt it ever deploy and ran on device.